# How to make a subscribe as a Observable?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-scala

I'm use RxScala/Java construct a Observable to emit socket connection with a loop,the result is every connection as a event.Like this,

```
val server = new ServerEntrance("localhost", 10002)
val socket: Observable[ConnectedSocket] = server.listen
```

After that, connection able to start reading.I need subscribe the `scoket` connection event and make it as a new Observable.
`ConnectedSocket` can use `stratReading`,return `Observable[CompletedProto]`,creating a Observable as connection do.It emit event with received information.I want to make this statement return `Observable[CompletedProto]`.How to construct it?

```
socket.subscribe(l => l.startReading)
```

If need detail information I really willing update it.

Comment: Have you looked at the `flatMap` or `flatMapLatest` operators?

Comment: @TamasHegedus, I have tried `flatMap` but if have multi subscriber the `startReading` will execute multi times.Caused `ReadPendingException` because `startReading` do a socket read operation multi times.I also confuse why Rx design map as this way.If you willing help me this question please [look here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala/issues/190).

Comment: Observables are replayable by default (I think that is their weakness in some scenarios). If you want to convert it to a hot observable you could use `.publish()` with an immediate `.connect()`, or you can ensure at most one subscribers with `.singleInstance()`